# Is the objective of this mutual fund only dividend return? (WILCX)

Tags: mutual-funds

Why does the share value decrease significantly every year but the growth of hypothetical 10k skyrocket?

The value of a share went from 14.12 Feb 2012 to 7.78 as of today.

I am unsure when to sell my shares in this fund due the significant loss in value over time. Is the yield supposed to make this a worthwhile investment that it can somehow combat the funds losses with reinvestment?

Comment: See also https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29768/if-stock-price-drops-by-the-amount-of-dividend-paid-what-is-the-use-of-a-divide, https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/27542/does-a-stock-really-dip-in-price-on-the-ex-dividend-date-and-why-would-it-do-th

Answer (score 3):

Share price is reduced by the amount of dividends and distributions on the ex-dividend date.  In order for the investment to achieve Total Return, share price must appreciate.

In this case, WILCX has paid a very large amount of distributions (lowering share price) and subsequent share price appreciation has caused the value of the investment to increase but it has not been enough to get share price back to its price of $14.12 in Feb 2012.